# How can I ensure gcc + libc has UTF-8 for multibyte strings and UTF-32 for wchar_t?

Tags: c, gcc, unicode, libc

I want to know how to force a GCC + GNU libc toolchain into normal Unicode behaviour, where the source code files encoding is UTF-8, and where the compiled program uses UTF-8 as its multibyte character set and UTF-32LE as its wchar_t, regardless of any locale info.

And I want to be able to know *at compile time* that it is going to work.

I know the normal answer is to use `setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8")`?, But it seems you can only know if setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf-8") is going to work at runtime, since only the "C" and "POSIX" locales are guaranteed to exist and, unless I'm missing something, you can't compile a locale into your executable.

GCC has these flags `-finput-charset=utf-8 -fexec-charset=utf-8 -fwide-exec-charset=utf-32le` but it is unclear how they work with setlocale().  If I used them, do I need to call setlocale()? Are they overridden by setlocale()?

It seems like there should be some reliable way to force gcc + libc into normal Unicode behaviour without having to know what locales are preinstalled on the source or target systems.

Comment: _"normal Unicode behaviour"_ - where is this "normal behaviour" defined?

Comment: The best way to do this is to *not use ISO C's locale facility at all.* Use something like ICU instead.

Comment: @zwol Yeah, probably. I've used libunistring, and GTK's glib. And they're fine. But it seems like you should be able to coerce gcc + gnu libc into this state.

Comment: You can't. But you don't want to anyway. I've fleshed out my comment into a proper explanation of why.

Comment: Why would you want to enforce "normal Unicode behaviour" (whatever that means) in an environment that is not set up to handle Unicode? Not asking how, but why?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I guess I think of it as "why should any modern application care if an environment refuses to use a UTF-8 locale.  The environment is broken, and maintaining software for it is pointless."

Comment: So call setlocale, and if it doesn't work, print a message and quit. Problem solved. But no, you want to force something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, and you don't want it anyway.

The interfaces defined by `locale.h` and `wchar.h` are a decade older than Unicode, and their data model is built around these assumptions:

1. There are many character sets and encodings, and *none* of them can necessarily represent all the characters your program might need to be able to handle over its lifetime.
2. However, any single *use* of your program will only need to process text from *one language*, and in *one encoding*.
3. Any one installation of the operating system will only need to process text in a small number of languages, knowable at installation time.

All three of these assumptions are invalid nowadays.  Instead we have:

1. There is a single character set (Unicode) whose design goal is to represent *all* of the world's living written languages (how close we come to achieving that goal depends on who you talk to and how seriously you take [Weinreich's Maxim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_language_is_a_dialect_with_an_army_and_navy)).
2. There are only a few encodings of *all of Unicode* to worry about, but data in 8-bit encodings that map to a *subset* of Unicode is still commonly encountered, and there are dozens of these.
3. It is normal for a single run of a program to need to process text in multiple languages and in many different encodings.  You can usually assume that a single *file* is all in one encoding, but not that you won't be called upon to merge data from sources in UTF-8, ISO-8859-2, and KOI8-R (for example).
4. The whole concept of an "installation" (one corporation, one sysadmin, a handful of shared minicomputers, tens or hundreds of [lusers](https://foldoc.org/luser)) is obsolete, and so is the idea that you won't wake up tomorrow and discover you've received email in a script you'd never even heard of before --- and the computer is still expected to render it correctly and recognize it for machine translation.

Because the data model is no good anymore, so too are the interfaces.  My honest recommendation is that you forget you ever heard of `locale.h` or any ISO C or POSIX interface that deals in `wchar_t`.  Instead use a third-party library (e.g. [ICU](https://icu.unicode.org/)) whose data model is a better fit for the modern world.

Types for characters and strings specifically encoded in UTF-n (n=8, 16, 32) have recently been added to the C standard, and in principle they should make this situation better, but I don't have any experience with them, and as far as I can tell the standard library barely takes notice of them.

(For more detail on the failings of the `locale.h` and/or `wchar_t` APIs and the present state of efforts to improve the C standard library, see https://thephd.dev/cuneicode-and-the-future-of-text-in-c.)

Comment: I suppose that's fair.  In this blog post, [https://thephd.dev/cuneicode-and-the-future-of-text-in-c] one of the people that sat on the C23 committee mentions that the committee believed that multibyte could be made to be UTF-8 and that wchar_t could be made to be UTF-(16 or 32), but, the committee didn't mandate that.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I've added it to the answer since it looks to have a much more detailed explanation of what's wrong with the legacy APIs.  I am not surprised that the committee was unable to reach consensus in favor of mandating encodings for either `char` or `wchar_t`, WG14 takes the "we can't change our dusty decks _at all_" constituency very seriously when it comes to this sort of thing (but not when it comes to aliasing, sigh).

Comment: (I suspect I'd make ThePhD's head explode if I told them that the 10-year release cycle for the C standard is a Good Thing in my book, and in fact it might be the only remaining reason why I would suggest the use of C for a new program...)