# How to handle UTF-16 strings across different platforms?

Tags: c, linux, windows, macos, winapi

When working with WinAPI, the type that is often used is wchar_t, however I have stumbled into many sources that say that wchar_t shouldn't be used on other platforms because it isn't standardized (UTF-16 on some platforms, UTF-32 on others, etc.).
If wchar_t isn't standardized, is there a type (preferably UTF-16) that can be reliably used across Windows, MacOS, and Linux that is also compatible with WinAPI, or any other way to ensure portability?

Comment: There's [`char16_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/char16_t). It's guaranteed to be capable of storing UTF-16 encoded code units, but it's not guaranteed to be *exactly* 16 bits wide.

Comment: But it will be if available, which is virtually guaranteed

Comment: @IInspectable Does this mean I can use char16_t for WinAPI too? I assume I'd need casting?

Comment: MS Visual C complies with `#include <uchar.h>` as mentioned in the C standard.

Comment: Since C strings are pointers, and C doesn't distinguish between pointer types you don't need any explicit casts in C. Might want to add some [compile time checks](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Static_assert) to verify that your assumptions about ABI compatibility are correct.

Comment: please just use UTF-8. Modern [Windows APIs already support UTF-8 for cross-platform compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63454192/995714)

Comment: @phuclv When calling into the Win32 API you certainly don't care about cross-platform compatibility. Enabling CP 65001 for a process is tedious, going through the translation is more expensive and introduces additional error modes and arbitrary limitations. And the majority of Windows' API surface doesn't even support character strings that aren't UTF-16. The *"UTF-8 Everywhere"* mantra is ill-informed.

Comment: Closely related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76864116

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/2259544/1216776

Comment: @IInspectable Have you ever wrote cross-platform apps? For portability one always have a platform-independent code where things like strings are stored and processed, and when calling system calls or Win32 APIs then they'll call platform-specific versions in the wrapper that are between `#ifdef`s. For example the window title or file names are computed separately in common code

Comment: @phuclv I believe I have never written a cross-platform application (outside of the UWP). I *have* written cross-platform library code, though, but that never forced me into using the same type to represent strings across platforms. Instead, all library code used the *native* string representation (for a given platform) internally, and provided a separate type at the interface, with configurable policies. The *"UTF-8 Everywhere"* Manifesto fails to make a convincing point why UTF-16 should not be the *internal* string encoding on Windows (or Java, or .NET, or ECMAScript, or...).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Newer versions of the standard provide `char16_t`, which will be capable of storing UTF-16.  However, the C standard doesn't guarantee that there are any types which are exactly 16 bits in size, so it could be larger than 16 bits.  As a practical matter, nobody uses machines without 16-bit integers, so you don't have to worry about that.

Having said that, UTF-16 is considered functionally obsolete on Unix outside certain programming languages (such as Java and JavaScript).  Unix systems overwhelmingly use UTF-8 (always without BOM) for data, and this is also the data format used by most cross-platform files and data interchange format (including HTML, JSON, and CBOR, among others).  The C standard library *does* support `wchar_t` on Unix, but this is almost always a 32-bit UTF-32 value and not UTF-16.  In addition, most of the Unix APIs will accept byte strings, which for text, is generally encoded in UTF-8 (but can often contain arbitrary non-NUL bytes) and there are no UTF-16 or UTF-32 versions at all.

As a result, there's no single standard encoding that you can use everywhere.  The [UTF-8 Everywhere site has a recommendation for dealing with Windows](https://utf8everywhere.org/#windows), which means that most data is stored in UTF-8 and converted directly around API calls.  This is very similar to the approach that Rust uses and is the one I'd recommend most for dealing with cross-platform software unless you're very certain that you need something different.